# MongoDB updating empty field after initial insert

Tags: angularjs, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, mean-stack

In the Mongoose schema there is an empty field for objectId of another table. I want to fill that field after the User object is created, as the school object is made after user object is.

User:

- name
- age
- dob
- company (this is object id from company table)

Initially I thought using the FindOneandUpdate() function would do this but I have had no luck.

Anyone any idea's?

**company.component.ts**

```
joinCompany(i){
 console.log(this.companyArr[i]._id);

 this.authService.addmoreUser(this.companyArr[i]._id).subscribe(data =>{
  if(data.success){
    this.router.navigate(['dashboard']);
  }
  else{
    this.flashMessages.show(data.msg,{cssClass: 'alert-
danger',timeout:3000});

  }
})
}
```

**auth.service.js**

```
addmoreUser(id){
  id = {companyid:id};
  console.log(id);
  let headers = new Headers();

  headers.append('Authorization', this.authToken);
  headers.append('Content-Type','application/json');
  return this.http.put('http://localhost:3000/users/pushCompanyintoUser',id,{headers:headers})
  .map(res => res.json());
}
```

**companies.js - CRUD file**

```
router.put('/pushCompanyintoUser', passport.authenticate('jwt', {session:false}), (req, res, next) => {
console.log(req.body);
 User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.user._id,{companyid:req.body} , function(err,user) {
    if (err) throw res.json({success:false, msg:'Failed to Update user!'});
    else res.json({success: true, msg:'User Updated!!'})

 });
});
```

That is from the angular frontend being passed to server and then trying to insert to db.

**DB Schema**

```
const UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
 fullname:{ type: String},
 email:{ type:String, required:true},
 username:{ type:String, unique:true,required:true  },
 companyid:{ type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Company', required:false}, <== (This is the where I am trying to submit to, in an object thats already made)
 dob:{ type:String, required:true },
 addressline:{ type:String, required:true },
 town:{ type:String,required:true },
 county:{  type:String,required:true},
 country:{ type:String, required:true},
 phone:{ type:Number, required:true },
 password:{ type:String, required:true }

});
```

The User object is inserted already just without a companyid, how do I go about adding the companyid after.

Comment: Show me your code

Comment: Updated question with code snippets from front to back end.

Comment: Does your company id prints out in console.log? which you have mentioned in company.js-CRUD file

Comment: It printed out the ID but not as ObjectId("f348453593gfb4f4"); just as {compid:"f348453593gfb4f4"}.

Comment: The update just fails. I think its because the User object that is already made.. e.g user named mark, I need to assign company id to mark and as company id field is empty and when user is searched in mongo shell it doesnt have a field called companyid because it wasn't populated on user Mark's initial creation.

Comment: Does your company collection is already created and are you passing the exact ID in your put method?

Comment: initially I passed from component to auth as a ID string not Object, then in the auth made an object, id = {companyid: id} and passed that through the put method. from there its received on serverside and used to try and populate User.companyid of the logged in user, I want to create a relationship between them that a user can have a company assigned to them(their current employer).